# how do I compare float variables in nano scale

Tags: python, floating-point

```
import math

dist = 1
wave = 500e-9
phase = 1

while math.isclose(phase,0) == False:
    dist += 1e-9
    x = dist % wave
    phase = (x % 1) * 2
    print(phase)
```

In Python, this is the code that I am trying to implement. I am trying to find the distance (starting at 1 meter when given a starting phase) that the phase of a wave is 2pi and the easiest way I found was to brute force every spot, however; because the wave is nanoscale I believe I am running into a conversion issue.
Any tips on how to get around the conversion issue?

Comment: You're running into floating point inaccuracy for sure. You could just scale up all of your units by, say, 1e6 and then deal with scaling them down again later.

Comment: I suggest following the suggestion of AKX and reading this excellent documentation page: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: `(x % 1) * 2` is never going to be 2pi, because `x % 1` is never going to be greater than 1. It's not clear what you're trying to do or why you're trying to do it this way, but it sounds like you could probably do it in a few lines of basic arithmetic with no brute-forcing.

Comment: Where in this code do you want to "compare" something and what is the problem with it?

Comment: Also, note that `math.isclose(x, 0)` is the same as `x == 0` because the default value of the `abs_tol` argument is `0.0` (see docs).

Comment: sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you elaborate more on the high level problem, that you tried to resolve with brute force? Probably there is a better way, with math.

Comment: You don't really need to "brute-force" the answer, you can do it using math. If you know the wavelength (`wl`) of the wave and its phase `p0` at a location `x0`, then the phase is `2*pi` at `x = x0 + wl * (2*pi - p0) / (2*pi) + n * wl` where `n` is a non-negative integer.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I am trying to model the double slit experiment when the phase of light entering either slit is different. my thought process is to find the distance that the phase of the light wave would be 2pi for both slits then to move a wavelength away from the spot i find until the two patterns overlap giving me the brightest band of light

Comment: @PranavHosangadi where did you find that equation? i have been looking for weeks for an equation like that

Comment: @Bill when i adjusted abs_tol i got the same result, and thank you i will definitely look into the docs more

Comment: @CameronAustin I have shown the reasoning behind the equation in [my answer below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75933439/843953) I did not find it anywhere, it is just math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to "brute-force" the answer, you can do it using math.

Consider the simple sine function `y = sin(2 pi * (x - x0) / wl + p0)` with starting conditions of `p0 = 115` degrees at `x0 = 0`, and a wavelength `wl = 2`

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


wl = 2
p0 = 115 * np.pi/180
x0 = 0

def func(x):
    return np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - x0) / wl + p0)


x = np.linspace(x0, 10, 10000)
y = func(x)
```

The phase changes by `2*pi` every time we move `wl` units in `x`. To figure out how much we must move in `x` to change the phase from `p0` to `2*pi`, we need to solve the equation:

```
 wl            ?
----  =  -------------
2*pi      (2*pi - p0)
```

which gives:

```
? = wl * (2*pi - p0) / (2*pi)
```

The phase of this wave is `2*pi` for the first time at `x = x0 + wl * (2pi - p0) / 2pi`. To get subsequent locations where the phase is `2*pi`, we simply need to go forward an integer multiple of wavelength. The general formula would be:

```
xphase_2pi = x0 + wl * (n + (2*pi - p0) / (2*pi))
```

Implementing this, we see:

<sup>Note: I used `n = np.arange(0, 5)` to simultaneously calculate 5 points where the phase is `2*pi`</sup>

```
xphase_2pi = x0 + wl * (np.arange(0, 5) + (2*np.pi - p0) / (2 * np.pi))
# array([1.36111111, 3.36111111, 5.36111111, 7.36111111, 9.36111111])

yphase_2pi = func(xphase_2pi)
# array([-2.44929360e-16, -4.89858720e-16, -7.34788079e-16, -9.79717439e-16,
       -1.22464680e-15])
```

As expected, `y` is effectively zero when the phase of a sine wave is `2*pi`.

We can also plot these values to make sure:

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x0, func(x0), 'ok')
plt.plot(xphase_2pi, yphase_2pi, 'xr')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

The plot shows that the red `x` symbols are all at the correct location: at zero when the wave is rising.

---

If you insist on doing it numerically, you can use one of the many amazing [zero-finding algorithms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#id2) that [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) comes with. You really don't need to build your own. For example, you could use [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) to solve the equation starting at your start location. If you find a zero where the slope is rising, you have your answer! If you find a zero where the slope is falling, add `wl/2` to that and you have your answer!

```
>>> x_zero = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, x0)
# array([0.36111111])
>>> xphase_2pi = x_zero + np.arange(0, 5) * wl
>>> delta_x = wl / 10000
... slope = (func(x_zero + delta_x) - func(x_zero - delta_x)) / (delta_x * 2)
# array([-3.14159245])
>>> if slope[0] < 0:
...    xphase_2pi += wl / 2
```

Which results in the same `xphase_2pi`:

```
array([1.36111111, 3.36111111, 5.36111111, 7.36111111, 9.36111111])
```

---

If you still want to build your own, [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) is a cool zero-finding algorithm you can implement. For convenience, we can define `func_slope`, a function that will return the slope of the wave at a given `x`. The slope is calculated as a [central difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) over `1/5000` of the wavelength, as we did above:

```
def func_slope(func, x):
    h = wl / 10000
    return (func(x + h) - func(x - h))/ (2 * h)

def newton(func, x0, max_iter=100):
    i = 0
    x = x0
    fx = func(x)
    fdx = func_slope(func, x)
    while not np.isclose(fx, 0) and i < max_iter:
        x = x - fx / fdx
        i += 1
        fx = func(x)
        fdx = func_slope(func, x)

    return x, fx, fdx, i
```

Now, you can call this function:

```
>>> x_zero, err, slope, iters = newton(func, x0)
# (0.36111111111454486, -1.0787248531787957e-11, -3.1415924468797582, 5)

>>> xphase_2pi = x_zero + np.arange(0, 5) * wl + (slope < 0) * wl / 2
# array([1.36111111, 3.36111111, 5.36111111, 7.36111111, 9.36111111])
```

Comment: I am getting lost on this equation that you made x = x0 + wl * (2pi - p0) / 2pi… y(x) = Asin(x)…..x which is the phase or 2pi is x = ((2pi*x0)/w1) + p0 which is where I am getting lost because if I was to continue manipulating this equation I would get x0 = (w1*(x - p0))/2pi or x0 = (w1*(2pi - p0))/2pi.. this equation looks super similar to yours but it’s different enough that I am not sure of your steps. Could you elaborate on how you found this? thanks friend

Comment: @CameronAustin The general equation of a wave is `y = A sin (2 pi / wl * (x - x0) + p0)` for a wave known to have phase `p0` at `x = x0`. With me so far? _Everything_ that is an argument to the `sin(...)` is the _"phase"_ of the wave, so `P = 2 pi / wl * (x - x0) + p0`. At `x = x0`, `P = p0`. This verifies our boundary condition. Now we know that the phase of a sine wave changes by `2pi` every time `x` changes by `wl`. And we know that it started at `p0`. So the equation with the unknown solves for how much we need to change `x` to reach a phase of `2pi` from `p0`. Better?

Comment: oh oh oh I see now! thanks friend, much better.